# How to resolve UITableView 'jump' when tapping status bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableViewController with custom cells that each contain a textField. Cells are added to the tableView by clicking an 'Add' button which calls the insertRows(at:with:) method. The cells have a reuseIdentifier and are being reused.

**The issue**:
Given the user has added a bunch of rows and is editing a textField in one of the bottom rows, when the user tries to scroll to the top by tapping the status bar at the top of the screen, then the tableView jumps / glitches on the first tap, but then scrolls to the top (as expected) after the user taps the status bar a second time.

> *Note: this jump / glitch doesn't occur when the textField being edited is the first textField to be edited in the tableView, it only occurs from the second edit onwards.*

**The goal**: For the tableView to scroll to the top when the status bar is tapped, without hiding the keyboard.

**Things I've tried**

- Manually setting tableView.scrollsToTop = true
- Adding tableView.beginUpdates() before calling insertRows(at:with:), and endUpdates() after
- Resigning first responder when textField finished editing
- Searching the web for many hours to understand why this is happening, to no avail

---

```
@IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
     let indexPath = IndexPath(row: cells.count, section: 0)
     cells.append(cell(text: ""))
     tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
} 

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

Attached GIF shows the jump / glitch when the user taps the status bar for the first time, followed by the expected behaviour when the status bar is tapped for the second time.
[TableView Jump / Glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtsM9.gif)

---

Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks in advance!